# PDF Javascript "Operation is not permitted" error

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe

I have been asked to create a PDF form that will be sent to a user, they fill it out and then they click a button on the PDF that emails it to a specified email address. I know this can easily be done in Adobe LiveCycle but we currently dont have that and I am trying to avoid using anything other than Acrobat and Reader. 
I am testing some things out and I have created a link on the page that uses the following JavaScript:
        this.submitForm({
        cURL: "mailto:me@emailaddress.com",
        cSubmitAs: "PDF"
        });

This works fine in Adobe Acrobat, but not in Reader (Which is what the users will view it in). When using the Adobe debugging console I get the following error message:
RaiseError: This operation is not permitted.
 Doc.submitForm:3:Link undefined:Mouse Up
 ===> This operation is not permitted.

Any idea what is happening and why Reader wont open it properly? Thanks in advance for all who contribute.

Comment: This isn't an answer, but all the PDF forms I've received have the following limitations: Acrobat Reader won't save your form answers, and it won't submit the form answers.  I believe this is a limitation of Acrobat Reader itself, but I don't have anything to back that up.  We've always been required to print the form and submit it in person.

Comment: I don't think you can submit this as PDF. I think it needs to be HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions of all files involved.  Often times the user trying to access content won't have the necessary privileges.

Comment: Permissions all seem fine, Im running a test and I have full control of the pdf file in question. Seems very odd that 2 programs written by the same company would behave so differently on the same thing.

Comment: @chiefly thats called "enterprisey" =p

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but here's the answer if you haven't figured it out, because I am in the middle of the same issue. :(

You cannot get Reader to submit as PDF w/o enabling those specific rights in the PDF document. And, the way to enable those rights is to purchase [Reader Extensions](http://www.adobe.com/products/livecycle/readerextensions/) to get that functionality turned on in the PDF you want filled out.

You can, however, send form data as FDF/XFDF w/o extensions. Basically, it's the user-supplied data stripped out of the PDF form and sent as FDF, X(ML)FDF or HTML.